# Mocha: using it-each with dependent variables

Tags: node.js, loops, mocha.js, supertest

So I've been having some trouble with the it-each module for loop testing in mocha. I'm using supertest, should and it-each modules.

```
var hasAccess = [{endpoint: "announcements", send: {"creator": users}}]
```

*users* is my varibale which is assigned in this test

```
it('users', function(done) {
        api.get('/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', devToken)
        .expect(200)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err)
            res.body[0].should.have.property('id')
            users = res.body[0].id                //<----------
            done()
        });
    });
```

My it-each

```
it.each(hasAccess, 'should return 201 perfoming a POST on %s', ['endpoint'], function(element, next) {

   console.log(element.send) //prints out "creator": undefined

   api.post('/' + element.endpoint)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', userToken)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .send(element.send)
        .expect(201)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            res.status.should.equal(201)
            next()
        });
});
```

Problem is, *hasAccess* is being passed into the it-each before *users* is assigned a value. I know it's bad practice to make tests dependent on each other, but there isn't really another way to test this. I need the id to completely test this. So any ideas?
Also there will be more objects in *hasAccess*, so a loop is the best way to do it. Just shortened it for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't make tests dependent on one another, but if you must...

The problem is not with `it.each` but with how you are storing the user id you get in your first test. You create your array like this:

```
var hasAccess = [{endpoint: "announcements", send: {"creator": users}}]
```

This takes the value from `users` for the `hasAccess[0].send.creator` field. It is `undefined` at that point so the field gets the value `undefined`. **From this point on, the changes you do to `users` *won't* affect the values stored in `hasAccess`.** If `users` were an object, then `hasAccess` would have a reference to that object and modifying the object would be reflected in `hasAccess` but it is a primitive value: `undefined`. So further changes to `users` have no effect here.

In order for the change to carry forward, your first test could get to the field by going through the `hasAccess` array.

Here's an illustration of how it could be done. I've simulated the asynchronous processes with `setTimeout`:

```
require("it-each")();
var assert = require("assert");

var users;
var hasAccess = [{endpoint: "announcements", send: {"creator": users}}];

it("get users", function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Wrong way:
        // users = "foo";

        // Right way:
        hasAccess[0].send.creator = "foo";
        done();
    }, 1000);
});


it.each(hasAccess, 'should return 201 perfoming a POST on %s', ['endpoint'],
        function(element, next) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                assert(element.send.creator === "foo");
                // console.log(element);
                next();
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Just got it working, thanks for the clear up on objects.